# How to get current stage name in task?

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I know how to fetch config vars with fetch() method, but can I get stage name (production, stage) in task?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found the answer: `fetch(:stage)`

Comment: You should post that as an answer, below, and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer: fetch(:stage)